# using a zipped file as a zsh parameter (converting from bash)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

This is a bash line that fails in zsh:

```
   
docker run --rm --volumes-from db_vol -v ~:/backup docker.hub.com/rainbows/db tar --exclude="*.log" -xzvf /backup/db_vol_latest.tar.gz
```

It looks like bash handles the `tar` file just fine but zsh isn't reading it in properly.  Anyone know how to write this line in zsh shell script?

Comment: It behaves differently in bash than it does in zsh so I believe it is.

Comment: Have you tried substituting `~` with the actual value?

Comment: I have now, it looks like it's working.  Thanks a bunch Ignacio.

Comment: What is `~:/backup` ? I think `bash` will convert that to `${PWD}:/backup` which doesn't make any sense on my system but maybe it does on yours. But `zsh` seems to want to look `:` up in `passwd`, and when it doesn't find it, it leaves the ~ in the argument.

Comment: @rici Yea, it seemed to be seeing the `~` and not replacing it, it makes sense now